# Being Freelance in France

Tags: france

I want to open a "micro-entreprise", which in France is the only status for freelancers. Until the last year, the "auto-entrepreneur" status was the best one to be freelance but it had been fused with the "micro-entreprise" status.

I am searching for information about this status, because it's a new one, there is not precise data for it on Internet.

If you have yourself opened a "micro-entreprise", could you explain me what you had to do to open it? In French, I also opened [a topic on developpez.net](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1816349/emploi-etudes-informatique/emploi/juridique/auto-entreprenariat-devient-micro-entreprise-commencer) forum.

Thank you!

Comment: Good question! I will be doing business travel in France soon, and also wondered how I could freelance legally if I ever moved there.

Answer (score 1):

The auto-entrepreneur business in France, also called micro-entrepreneur, was launched in France in 2009 for small businesses. It offers a simple legal structure for sole traders, who will be paying their social charges based on their turnover.

An auto-entrepreneur business can be registered online and the social charges can also be declared online.

This [site](http://www.startbusinessinfrance.com/blog/post/summary-of-changes-to-the-auto-entrepreneur-business-in-2017) has lot of up-to-date info regarding fees, rules, and changes made in 2017.  I've included other helpful links.

- https://www.auto-entrepreneur.fr/
- https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/
- http://www.startbusinessinfrance.com/auto-entrepreneur

Comment: I'm looking for the changes which apply since january 2018, do you have documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

Micro-entreprise is only a new fuzzy word for auto-entrepreneur. There is no difference, and it is habitually used to refer as the tax regime for this type of entrepreneurs.

To open one, you should simply consider doing your demand on the official website https://www.lautoentrepreneur.fr/

What to know about the status :

- You can have the [ACCRE](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11677), giving you degressive exoneration of taxes in the span of 3 years (only if you meet certains conditions)
- The tax floor has changed in 2018, it has pretty doubled for all types of enterprise, see [here](https://www.auto-entrepreneur.fr/statut-auto-entrepreneur/limites/plafonds.html). The mere change is that you can now have collecting and disbursment of TVA if you exceed some revenues thresold
- You have to open a bank account [separated from your personal one](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000029959650&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006073189), but it don't have to be a professional one

Globally, it is pretty easy to handle the administratives task of an `auto-entreprise` because you don't have to make an accounting. But as this changed in 2018 with the doubling up of the turnover, if you now exceed 32 270€, you have to pay the TVA and thus make some accounting things that makes the things a bit harder.

Comment: Thank yo ufor the information! I have another question about the status: if I make applications for people, do I need to declare my company as "Commerce"?

Comment: Sorry for the response delay ;), No you don't, you're considered as a liberal activity and thus not a regular commercial one needing to be registered in the [RCS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registre_du_commerce_et_des_soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9s_(France))